# How to fix for loop isn’t getting results in string array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, find

I’m creating a music player, and I ran into a problem with a for loop and an array. I have the following function in my main.js file

```
function CreateDatabaseArtists() {
  for (n = 0; n < DatabaseArtists.length+1; n++) {
    if (DatabaseArtists[n.toString()].name === "") {} else {      
      let NewArtistBtn = document.createElement("div");
      NewArtistBtn.id = DatabaseArtists[n].artistgroup;
      // NewArtistBtn.onclick = function() {OpenArtist(NewArtistBtn.id);};
      NewArtistBtn.classList.toggle("column");
      NewArtistBtn.setAttribute("style", "word-wrap: break-word; float: none; width: 150px; text-align:center;align-items:center; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;");           
      let ArtistIMG = document.createElement("img");
      if (DatabaseArtists[n].ArtistArt == "") {
        ArtistIMG.src = "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p298.png";
        ArtistIMG.style.borderRadius = "50%";
      } else {
        ArtistIMG.src = DatabaseArtists[n].ArtistArt;
        ArtistIMG.style.borderRadius = "50%";
      }
      ArtistIMG.style.width = "150px"; ArtistIMG.style.height = "150px";
      NewArtistBtn.appendChild(ArtistIMG);
      let text = document.createElement("p");
      text.innerHTML = "ahhh-humbug";
      // DatabaseArtists[b].name;
      ArtistIMG.setAttribute("aria-label", text.innerHTML);
      NewArtistBtn.appendChild(text);
      document.getElementById("artists").appendChild(NewArtistBtn);
    }
  }
}
```

And the part with

```
for (n = 0; n < DatabaseArtists.length+1; n++) {
        if (DatabaseArtists[n.toString()].name === "") {}
```

Keeps failing, I get an error message saying that it cant find the variable for “name” even though in the array it is `"name": "AJR", "explicit": false, "artistgroup": "ajr", "ArtistArt": ""`
What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? And the output for `console.log(DatabaseArtists[n.toString()])`?

Comment: Have you initialised the ‘n’ var somewhere else in your code? That could be your issue if you haven’t. var n = 0;

Comment: @LloydNicholson no I haven’t, its is the first and only “n” variable in my code.

Comment: @Samsquanch the error code is just “cant find variable DatabaseArtists[n].name”

Comment: @RidleyNelson initialise it in the for loop then. var n = 0;

Comment: Like for (n = 0; n < DatabaseArtists.length+1; n++) {var n=0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (n = 0; n < DatabaseArtists.length+1; n++)
```

You are iterating past the end of the array, so the last loop will try to access the `name` property on `undefined`. The index should go from `0` to `length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Honest bit of advice, why don't you break up the application, it's just easier to maintain that way. Also if you use a `forEach` method, you don't have to worry about index to the same extent as you would if you used a tradtitional `for` loop.

```
const defaultStyle = "word-wrap: break-word; float: " +
  "none; width: 150px; text-align:center;align-items:center; " +
  "display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; " +
  "overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;";
const defaultImg = 'https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p298.png';
const appRoot = document.getElementById("artists");


const createImage = artist => {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  const source = artist.ArtistArt === '' ? defaultImg : artist.ArtistArt;

  img.src = source;
  img.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  img.style.width = "150px";
  img.style.height = "150px";

  return img;
};


const createButton = artist => {
  const btn = document.createElement("div");
  const img = createImage(artist);
  const ptag = document.createElement("p");

  ptag.innerHTML = "ahhh-humbug";
  btn.id = artist.artistgroup;
  btn.classList.toggle("column");

  btn.setAttribute("style", defaultStyle);
  btn.appendChild(img);
  btn.appendChild(ptag);

  return btn;
};


const createDatabaseArtists = () => {
  databaseArtists.forEach(artist => {
    if (artist.name !== '') {
      appRoot.appendChild(createButton(artist));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! If it weren’t for you, I probably wouldn’t of even thought about using a forEach statement.

Comment: @RidleyNelson it's fine, I'm glad that I was of help! :) I've been trying to get myself into writing my JavaScript in a more functional style for some time now, and usign methods such as ```forEach``` or ```map```, etc, makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Cool. I just ran into a problem, what is the value of artist?